# Fading in canvas elements doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, path, fadein

I've trying to solve this problem and I can't figure it out. Basically I want to create a bunch of triangles that fade in one by one (right now I only have one triangle because I'm still testing this so there is no point on adding a bunch of triangles/lines). To achieve this I use a setInterval method.

```
//Canvas
var position = 0;
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas-1");
var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var triangles=[];
var time;
function Triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,alpha){
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.x3 = x3;
    this.y3 = y3;
    this.alpha = alpha;
}
function alphatime(a){
    if(time > 100) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return time / 100;
    }
}
triangles.push(new Triangle(0,0,100,100,300,150,0));
function Next(){
    if(position<triangles.length){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(triangles[position].x1, triangles[position].y1); 
        ctx.lineTo(triangles[position].x2, triangles[position].y2);
        ctx.lineTo(triangles[position].x3, triangles[position].y3);
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(0,0,0,'+ alphatime(triangles[position].alpha) +')';
        ctx.stroke();
        position++;
    }
}

function timeCount(){
    for (var i=0; i<triangles.length; i++) {
        if(triangles[i].alpha<100){
            triangles[i].alpha=(triangles[i].alpha + 1);
            console.log(triangles[i].alpha, typeof triangles[i].alpha);
        }
    }
}
var trianglesAppear = setInterval(Next, 800);
var fade = setInterval(timeCount,25);
```

For some reason instead of appearing slowly it just appears suddenly like when triangle[i].alpha is like 40. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was badly written. I didn't fully understand the concept of the requestAnimationFrame() method, so I tried using different ways of doing it and this was one of them, but it's better to use requestAnimationFrame(). If anyone else is having problems I suggest you guys watch this series of videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EO6OkltgudE&list=PLpPnRKq7eNW3We9VdCfx9fprhqXHwTPXL

This is the new code, using requestAnimationFrame();

```
//Canvas 1
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas-1");
var ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var triangles=[];
function Line(x1,y1,x2,y2,alpha){
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.alpha = alpha;
}
var alphaspeed=0.05;
triangles.push(new Line(0,400,50,250,0));
triangles.push(new Line(90,400,50,250,0));
triangles.push(new Line(50,250,0,180,0));
triangles.push(new Line(90,400,150,290,0));
triangles.push(new Line(150,290,250,400,0));
triangles.push(new Line(150,290,50,250,0));
triangles.push(new Line(0,180,80,200,0));
triangles.push(new Line(50,250,80,200,0));
triangles.push(new Line(80,200,65,110,0));
triangles.push(new Line(65,110,0,180,0));
triangles.push(new Line(65,110,0,0,0));
triangles.push(new Line(80,200,150,290,0));
triangles.push(new Line(150,290,220,300,0));
triangles.push(new Line(220,300,250,400,0));
triangles.push(new Line(150,290,200,150,0));
triangles.push(new Line(200,150,80,200,0));
triangles.push(new Line(220,300,350,400,0));
triangles.push(new Line(220,300,275,175,0));
triangles.push(new Line(150,290,275,175,0));
triangles.push(new Line(275,175,200,150,0));
triangles.push(new Line(200,150,135,115,0));
triangles.push(new Line(135,115,80,200,0));
triangles.push(new Line(135,115,65,110,0));
triangles.push(new Line(65,110,250,50,0));
triangles.push(new Line(135,115,250,50,0));
triangles.push(new Line(200,150,250,50,0));
triangles.push(new Line(275,175,305,100,0));
triangles.push(new Line(200,150,305,100,0));
triangles.push(new Line(305,100,250,50,0));
triangles.push(new Line(250,50,335,0,0));
triangles.push(new Line(305,100,335,0,0));
triangles.push(new Line(335,1,415,1,0));
triangles.push(new Line(305,100,415,1,0));
triangles.push(new Line(1,1,1,399,0));
triangles.push(new Line(1,399,350,399,0));
function Next(){
    for(var i=0; i<triangles.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            if(triangles[i].alpha<1){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(triangles[i].x1, triangles[i].y1); 
                ctx.lineTo(triangles[i].x2, triangles[i].y2);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                triangles[0].alpha+=alphaspeed;
                ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(0,0,0,'+ triangles[i].alpha +')';
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
        else{
            if(triangles[i-1].alpha>1){
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
                for(var o=0; o<(i); o++){
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(triangles[o].x1, triangles[o].y1); 
                    ctx.lineTo(triangles[o].x2, triangles[o].y2);
                    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                    triangles[0].alpha=1.01;
                    ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(0,0,0,'+ triangles[o].alpha +')';
                    ctx.stroke();
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(triangles[i].x1, triangles[i].y1); 
                ctx.lineTo(triangles[i].x2, triangles[i].y2);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                triangles[i].alpha+=alphaspeed;
                ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(0,0,0,'+ triangles[i].alpha +')';
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }

    if(triangles[(triangles.length-1)].alpha>1){
        cancelAnimationFrame(Next);
    }
    else{
        requestAnimationFrame(Next);
    }
}
Next();
```